# Bind YAML properties to Map<String, List<String>> type with Spring Boot

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot, yaml

I know that if I put the properties in the .yml file like that:

```
list
  - item 1
  - item 2
```

I can bind them to a `java.util.List` or `Set` type. Also If yaml properties are like that:

```
map:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
```

I can bind thet to a Map. I wonder though if it is possible to bind yml properties to a `Map<String, List<String>>` type..

Answer (score 6):

try to add this:

```
private Map<String, List<String>> keysList;
```

and put this in your .yml file

```
keysList:
    key1: 
        - value1
        - value2  
    key2: 
        - value2
        - value3
    key3: 
        - value3
        - value4
```

The result should be List mapping:

**keysList={key1=[value1, value2], key2=[value2, value3], key3=[value3, value4]}**

If you use on this way

```
private Map keysList;
```

you will get Map mapping.

**keysList={key1={0=value1, 1=value2}, key2={0=value2, 1=value3}, key3={0=value3, 1=value4}}**

Comment: Any idea why it binds to a map with numbered keys by default? (also observed with a `Map<String, Object>`)

Comment: in this case, if my keys having space that space is removed, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

thanks it helped me :) more descriptive answer I'm posting here.

Config class -

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "configuration.mymapwithlist")
public class ConfigUtilClass implements IConfigUtilClass {
    private Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Map<String, List<String>> getMyMap() {
        return myMap;
    }

}
```

yaml -

```
configuration: 
    mymapwithlist:
        myMap:
            key1:
                - value 1
                - value 2
                - value 3
                - value 4
            key2:
                - value 1
                - value 2
                - value 3
                - value 4
            '[key 3]':
                - value 1
                - value 2
                - value 3
                - value 4
            '[key 4]':
                - value 1
                - value 2
                - value 3
                - value 4
```

if your keys having spaces then, put keys in [ key 4 ].