# Maps in placeholder Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, configuration, yaml

How can I pass the default map type values to the configuration class in a scenario where I have to use an injection placeholder:

```
foo:
  bar:
    mappedVariable: ${INJECTIBLE_MAP:{desired:'mapHere'}}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'foo.bar.mappedVariable' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>:

    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>]

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've also tried referencing values results seems to be the same:

```
foo:
  bar:
    mappedVariable: ${INJECTIBLE_MAP:${foo.bar.initalValues}}
    initialValues:
    ...
```

Changing variable name in configuration class to initialValues works perfectly fine, but I need to have the injection possibility.

Comment: Check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510151/bind-yaml-properties-to-mapstring-liststring-type-with-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510151/bind-yaml-properties-to-mapstring-liststring-type-with-spring-boot)

Comment: I think my question is different. I am not trying to bind Mat<String,List<String>>, I rather need Map<String,String>